# How to disable workflow initiated email from SP workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

I have a workflow in SharePoint 2013 that sends out emails to the user whenever their requests gets worked on. They however also get an email that says "A workflow has been initiated on the following list item".

Is there any way to disble that email from being generated or sent to the requestor?

Please advise, thank you.

Comment: Have  you  developed custom workflow or OOTB workflow of sharepoint ?

Comment: It is an OOTB workflow

Answer (score 0):

With SharePoint Designer, you can change or simply remove the initial email send to the Author.
There are some workaround to do, since you'll have to copy the OOTB Workflow before editing him.

Comment: Thanks but I simply created my own SharePoint Workflow using designer which is more malleable to my needs. It brings out its own new set of headaches however.